# Is it possible to construct a given cube?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, geometric-construction

Is it possible to construct, with unmarked ruler and a compass, a cube whose volume equals to a given sphere?

I tried to construct the given cube but I can't see a light of constructing it, maybe it is impossible to construct? If that's the case I think galois theory might help to show this. Is there any problem related to this kind of problem before? 
 
Any help and hint would be much appreciated thank you very much!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.